# Is there a tool to convert original trait bounds to where clauses?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy, rustfmt

Is there a tool that can convert original trait bounds like this:

```rust
fn foo<V: Debug>(value: V) {
   // ...
}
```

to the "newer" ([2014](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0135-where.md)) where clause:

```rust
fn foo<V>(value: V)
where
    V: Debug,
{
    // ...
}
```

?

This is mostly a stylistic choice; since discussions around those can raise tensions, being able to enforce this (f.e. in CI) would be valuable. Can `rustfmt` or `clippy` do this?

Comment: There is none yet but there is an [issue to add a clippy lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/9720)

Answer (score 1):

Rust-analyzer can do this. In VSCode, if you put the cursor in the angle brackets and run quick-fix (<kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> by default), Rust analyzer will suggest moving the bound to a where clause, as shown below.

[image: Screenshot of VSCode Rust code and RA]